# iphone How to make custom UISwitch with three states (options)

Tags: iphone, uiswitch, uicontrol

I want to make Switch, which have three states.Basically I need to store value 0 or 1 or 2.
By checking the state of Switch.

Please Help to make this switch.If it can be made Using IB that will be very nice because it will be easy to place in the right place.

(I have image but not able to show bec am new, dont have 10 reputation yet)

Thanks in advance for your creative thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a UISegmentedControl for this. It's part of the standard set of controls, Apple has taken care of accessibility support, and users will know what to do with it.

Making a custom control that looks like UISwitch but behaves differently is a bad idea.